# How and when Android auto connects to a bluetooth device?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a BLE device that I am currently programming, and I would like my Android to auto connect to this BLE device, if it is advertising and if it is already paired.
I know that it is possible, because I already have a bluetooth device that do such a thing.
Is it something that has to be set from the BLE peripheral ? Or from the phone itself ? I am really curious about that, thanks.

Comment: wouldn't the android device just detect it, recognise the BLE device's address in a scan, and issue a connect request?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Android Bluetooth API does not provide this feature.

I have tried to achieve auto reconnection using [BluetoothDevice#connectGatt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#connectGatt(android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback)), with "autoConnect" set to true but it did not work at all.

Like Joe suggested in the comments, I would go for my own implementation, handling both the scanning process and the connection process.